# Modularization of html content in Electron app

Tags: html, node.js, electron

I know a typical practice to build an Electron app is to follow SPA (Single Page App). I still would like to split my html content into separate files for easy maintenance. There is still the main `index.html` file which is to be loaded on startup.

My question is: is there a protocol for *inserting* a part of html content from a different files? For eg. in Django, there is a `include` and `extend` tags where you can insert an entire html file into the body of another parent html file or retain certain features from another html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this directly. Django is a server-side framework, so you can assemble your HTML on the server, and the completed HTML is sent to the client/browser. With Electron, you're basically running Chromium with Node.js APIs added, loading your HTML from the filesystem, so there's no server to do any HTML assembly in.

However, if you just want to break up your HTML into pieces for easier maintenance, but you're not doing any of your `include`/`extend` dynamically, theoretically, you could use some kind of templating system or a static site generator to combine your HTML files statically at build time.

- Here's an list of some JS templating engines: https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html
- Here's a list of some static site generators (filter language by JavaScript): https://jamstack.org/generators/

Comment: Thanks for explaining.